# Why can't I use let bindings to pattern match a 3-tuple in Coq?

Tags: coq

Consider the following

```
Axiom foo : nat -> nat * nat.

Definition fooX (x : nat) := 
  let (y, z) := foo x in
  y + z.
```

which is fine.

Now, consider

```
Axiom bar : nat -> nat * nat * nat.

Definition barX1 (x : nat) := 
  match bar x with
  | (y, z, w) => y + z + w
  end.
```

which is also fine.

But I cannot seem to do this

```
Definition barX2 (x : nat) :=
  let (y, z, w) := bar x in
  y + z + w.
```

I get the error `Error: Destructing let on this type expects 2 variables.`

How do I deconstruct thruples with let pattern matches? Also, does Gallina allow Haskell like `where` constructs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write :

```ml
Definition barX2 (x : nat) :=
  let '(y, z, w) := bar x in
  y + z + w.
```

See [here](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/language/extensions/match.html#second-destructuring-let-syntax)

Comment: Thanks. I never would have guessed!